# How to use registerMetatag in Yii 2

Tags: yii2

i'm trying to render meta tag on page header by use:
In my View:

```
<?php
$this->registerMetaTag(['name' => 'keywords', 'content' => 'yii, framework, php']);
?>
```

and in my layout i put this code in head tag position:

```
<?php $this->head()?>
```

But it does not working. Anyone who have the same problem, can help me solve this problem. Thank you !!

Comment: This should work, please add more details about your views and controller action.

Comment: Register MetaTag in View or Controller are doing the same thing.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To define a meta tag through the `registerMetaTag` method, use the following code in your controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    \Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag([
        'name' => 'description',
        'content' => 'Description of the page...'
    ]);
    return $this->render('index');
}
```

and this markup in the layout:

```
<head>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
```

I've updated the basic demo application (from http://www.yiiframework.com/download/) that you can download here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/9rarzhtw65e5zo1/basic.zip?dl=0 and see this approach in action.